# How to add another circle in java coding

Tags: java, swing, coding-style, awt, paint

so today I'm was making a program and as i'm still a beginner I'm still learning but i'd like to know how to add another circle, for instance I have two units, Red and Blue, I have added the randomize which randomly selects the x and y position, but when I click start it only shows one circle which is red, the blue one is not even there, I know i have not done some coding, but here's my program, please help thanks :)

so yh :) thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to add some [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/collections/)`like List/ArrayList`, where you can keep each instance of your Circle, which you can draw later on. An [example](http://gagandeepbali.uk.to/gaganisonline/swing/downloads/PaintingCircles.java) for your help. The points mentioned in the answer below are no doubt need to be valued, as they do tell, as to what you doing wrong in your approach :-)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  (One without a dozen text fields, an import for `java.applet.Applet` & which is clearly using a combination of Swing & AWT (e.g. `TextField`) components unnecessarily.   In this case you would use a `JTextField`.

Comment: And Swing is double buffered by default so you don't need to worry about double buffering.

Answer (score 5):

A few things to change here:

- Drop all AWT components (Canvas, Panel, etc...) and  replace them with their equivalent Swing one (`JPanel`, `JTextField`...). This will avoid rendering issues and bring double buffering (without any code to perform).
- Don't ever use `c.getGraphics()`.
- Override `paintComponent(Graphics g)` and use the `Graphics g` parameter provided there (see also this [link for some example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step2.html))
- To perform "animation" use a `javax.swing.Timer`. All updates to the UI must be done on the EDT (Event Dispatching Thread). Read also about [concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)
- When using `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` (or any other dialog), provide a valid `parent` component and not `null`. This will allow proper parenting of windows (avoiding dialogs to be hidden by other frames).